# событие смены вкладки в jq ui tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, javascript

помогите пожалуйста исправить ситуацию

формирую блок с вкладками при помощи jquery ui tabs. задача в том чтобы при смене вкладки срабатывало некоторое событие. здесь нерабочий живой пример http://prozaik.16mb.com/js/tab/

в то же время в сети есть много примеров, в которых подобная конструкция работает. [ссылка1](http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/km7Le/), [ссылка2](http://jsfiddle.net/yunowork/KhwZS/1130/)

ps
в идеале мне хотелось бы чтобы срабатывало несколько событий в определенной последовательности. например в последнем происходит нужное мне действие, в первом - проверка разрешения на это действие

Comment: >есть много примеров, в которых подобная конструкция работает.

Я не очень понимаю, зачем задавать здесь вопрос, Вы ведь нашли работающий код? Хотите несколько событий при нажатии? -Добавьте функцию с этим событием в нужное Вам мест.

Comment: этот работающий код у меня не работает. я страничку показал даже